# hibernate query to fetch data from different master tables

Tags: hibernate

I have a table with a lot of references to other master tables, I want to know how to fetch data from all these tables for a particular record. Like say my tables has the following column:

`ID(PK)`, `FName`,`LName`,`Market_ID`,`Sector_id`,`Currency_id` and so on.

I want to fetch a record for a particular but instead of the ids I need to actual names of the master table entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a direct way but, you can do a @Manytoone Mapping to the master table, the resulting entity will be like below

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="sector_id",cascade_type= Cascade.all,lazy=true)
private MAsterTable sector_id;
```

I've not compiled or anything, but you get the idea. later you have to call this `sector_id.getName()`;